# JOptionPane stops execution flow

Tags: java, swing, java-7, windows-10-desktop

I've developed a jar file, that does some processing on the current computer. At a point a JOptionPane is displayed with the following code:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        context.getApplication().getApplicationFrame(), selectionPane, 
        Translation.t("ui.standardReplicaSelectionDialog.title"), 
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
    );

    if(result != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        // quit
        context.getApplication().exit(0);
    }
```

Now, i have the problem, that, if i call the jar from cmd line, the app runs through as expected. The JOptionPane is displayed, after clicking "cancel", the application is closed via exit(0). If "ok" is clicked, the application goes further.

But my application should be startet by an exe, that is not developed by me. When my jar is started by this exe, after displaying JOptionPane and clicking ok or cancel nothing happens, the flow stops until i kill the exe via task manager. After that, the flow goes forward as excpected.....
Really strange, any ideas?

Comment: *"any ideas?"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: how do you create the exe? there are different tools for this, and they might behave different, so it's important to know more about it.